# If an element x of S satisfies exactly r of the t conditions, how many times is x counted in the following expressions?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

> Use the standard notation for Inclusion-Exclusion ($S$ is a set of $N$ elements, ${c_1} {c_2} ...{c_t}$ are conditions
>   on the elements of $S$, and $N({c_i}_1 {c_i}_2...{c_i}_m)$ is the number of elements of $S$ satisfying all of conditions ${c_i}_1 {c_i}_2...{c_i}_m)$. If an element x of S satisfies exactly r of the t conditions, how many times is x counted in the
>   following expressions?

Here are the notations used:
$$1)\sum_{i<j}N(c_ic_j)$$
This the summation of all possible combinations without repetition of elements in $1\leq i\lt j\le t$, then is the answer $\binom{t}{2} \binom{t}{x}$?

$$2) \sum_{i\ne j}N(c_ic_j)$$
I guessing that notation $(1)=(2)$

The following notations I don't understand:
$$3)\sum_{i,j,k}N(c_i c_j c_k)$$
$$4)\sum_{i,j,k,l \textrm{ distinct and } i<j \textrm{ and } k>l} N(c_i c_j c_k c_l)$$
$$5)\sum_{i,j,k,l \textrm{ satisfying } l<j<k } N(c_i c_j c_k c_l)$$

Comment: $(1)\neq (2)$ rather $2*(1)=(2)$ because there is an order involved in $(1).$<br> Now, $(1)$ as $x$ has $r$ options, then $x$ appears $\binom{r}{2}$ So what do you mean by $\binom{t}{x}??$

Comment: @phicar oic, 2nd notation allows i and j to be less or greater than each other. $\binom{t}{x}$ is just a guess.

Comment: Yes, that's why $(1)\neq (2).$ Well, the guess doesnt makes sense sadly because $x$ is not a number rather than an element that has certain properties. consider $\binom{r}{2}$ because you have to pick $2$ properties that $x$ has, $x$ has $r$ properties, so in that number of chooses you are counting $x$.